# Mysql and PHP Problem?

Tags: php, mysql

It seems there is a parse error with my mysql and php code can some please help me clean up this code.

```
        $tag = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['tag']);
        $query = 'UPDATE tags SET count = count+1 WHERE tag = '.$tag;
        mysql_query($query,$dbc);
        if( !mysql_affected_rows() ) {
          $query = 'INSERT INTO tags (tag,count) VALUES('.$tag.',1)';
          if (mysql_query($query,$dbc));
          {
          die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
          }
        echo "1 record added";

        mysql_close($dbc)
```

Answer (score 2):

Some problems: Missing **}**, **;** after **if**, missing **;**, dying on success (second query), **$tag** not in quotes:

```
$tag = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['tag']);
$query = "UPDATE tags SET count = count+1 WHERE tag = '".$tag."'";
mysql_query($query,$dbc);
if( !mysql_affected_rows() ) {
   $query = "INSERT INTO tags (tag,count) VALUES('".$tag."',1)";
   if ( !mysql_query($query,$dbc) )
   {
       die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
   }
   echo "1 record added";
}

mysql_close($dbc);
```

That seems about it, at least **if $dbc is a valid connection**...

Comment: You mean quotes and not parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

```
   $tag = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['tag']);
    $query = 'UPDATE tags SET count = count+1 WHERE tag = "'.$tag.'"';
    mysql_query($query,$dbc);
    if( !mysql_affected_rows() ) {
      $query = 'INSERT INTO tags (tag,count) VALUES("'.$tag.'",1)';
      if (!mysql_query($query,$dbc))
      {
      die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
      }
    echo "1 record added";
    }

    mysql_close($dbc);
```

Missing a semicolon on the last line

PS: Giving us the parse error makes finding the answer much easier.

Comment: I get this error now 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in

Comment: Remove the semicolon at the end of the 2nd if statement. (I fixed my code)

Comment: And You forgot to close the first if statement

Comment: it kind of works now, but it wont update my database now wierd.

Comment: The if statement with the mysql_query() needs to be checking for a false, right now it checks for a true, which means that the query worked.

Comment: Well, if it isn't updating you actual mysql database, you might have a mysql error or something, which I can't really fix.

Comment: SHould I post the whole script?

Comment: Well, first try and debug it. Put echos in all of the if statements to see exactly what is happening. (What is the query, are there any mysqsl_error()s, etc)

Comment: No more mysql errors the form is displayed I did something wrong though?

Comment: Yes, something is wrong if it isn't updating. You might want to open up another question/answer about that, since it is a separate problem. In that you might want to post the full code too.

Comment: okay thanks for all the help. and thanks every one for trying.

Comment: Use 'single quotes', not "double-quotes" for SQL string literal delimiters. Double-quotes is MySQL-only that means something quite different in ANSI SQL and will fail on most other databases, as well as on MySQL itself under various configurations. Single quotes work everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the problem with your script like single quotes not ended properly.

Here is corrected code

```
<?php 
        $tag = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['tag']);

        $query = "UPDATE tags SET count = count+1 WHERE tag = '".$tag."'";

        mysql_query($query,$dbc);

        if( !mysql_affected_rows() ) {

          $query = "INSERT INTO tags (tag,count) VALUES('".$tag.",1)";

          if (mysql_query($query,$dbc))

          {

          die('Error: ' . mysql_error());

          }

        echo "1 record added";


        mysql_close($dbc)

?>
```